# Preview says "The file couldn't be saved" for a pdf document

Tags: pdf, preview

Note this is *different from the similar question [Preview fails to save pdf forms](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387927/preview-fails-to-save-pdf-forms) because that other question is about pdf *forms* but this is one is just a normal pdf.

I am using `Preview` for the first time on `Catalina` - but am a veteran on earlier platforms. I am unable to save an updated PDF

[image]

This is a PDF that I added some textboxes and a `Tools|Annotations|Signature`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it one specific PDF or all PDF's?  Can you save it when you remove the annotations?  I *think* once you add annotations to the doc, you can't save it.

Comment: Looks like I _can_ `duplicate`/`rename`/`save`  a non-modified PDF. Wow ok.. Pls make this an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you annotate a regular PDF doc, Preview will prevent you from directly saving the file.

You will have to remove the annotations or, as you already found, do a Print -> Save to PDF.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround I did a `Print|Save to PDF` . That does work.